# Number of samples for Hoeffding's Bound with Gaussian R.V

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, bounds

I am trying to obtain the required number of sample $n$ for a given confidence interval $\alpha$ and $X_1 ... X_n$ which are Gaussian rv with $\mu$ mean and $\sigma^2$ variance. I know that
\begin{equation}
Pr(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu \geq t) \leq \exp{(\frac{-nt^2}{2\sigma^2})}.
\end{equation}
yet, I don't know how to progress. How does $\alpha$ enter the picture and leads me to obtain $n$?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Are you looking for $n$ such that your confidence interval on the mean will be a given width? According to the (Wikipedia) definition of Hoeffding's Bound, "Hoeffding's inequality provides an upper bound on the probability that the sum of bounded independent random variables deviates from its expected value by more than a certain amount." Gaussian R.V.s are not bounded so I'm not sure Hoeffding is relevant here.

Comment: Precisely, I would like to find the lower bound for $n$ that satistfies such an $\alpha = \Pr[\textbf{X} \in [\mu \pm \sigma]] \leq \exp(.)$ so that I can find a $n$ in terms of $\alpha$. So what Im looking for is a lower bound, not UB.

Comment: Sorry - can you please be more specific? I don't understand what your equation in the last comment is representing.